# I am having a hard time understanding the concept of Ordering in OPTICS Clustering algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, optics-algorithm

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of Ordering in OPTICS Clustering algorithm.

I Would be grateful if someone gives a logical and intuitive explanation of the ordering and also explain what `res$order` does in the following code and what is the reahability plot(which can be obtained by the command 'plot(res)').

```
library(dbscan)

set.seed(2)
n <- 400

x <- cbind(
  x = runif(4, 0, 1) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1),
  y = runif(4, 0, 1) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1)
  )

plot(x, col=rep(1:4, time = 100))


res <- optics(x, eps = 10,  minPts = 10)
res

res$order
plot(res)
```

res$order gives the following output:

> [1]   1 363 209 349 337 301 357 333 321 285 281 253 241 177 153  57 257  29  77 169 105 293 229 145 181 385 393 377 317 381 185 117
>    [33] 101   9  73 237 397 369 365 273 305 245 249 309 157 345 213 205  97  49  33  41 193 149  17  83 389  25 121 329   5 161 341 217
>    [65] 189 141  85  53 225 313 289 261 221 173  69  61 297 125  81 133 129 197 109 137  59  93 165  89  21  13 277 191 203 379 399 375
>    [97] 351 311 235 231 227  71  11 299 271 291 147  55  23 323 219 275  47 263   3 367 331 175  87 339 319 251 247 171 111 223  51  63
>   [129] 343 303 207 151 391 359 287 283 215 143 131 115  99  31 183  43 243 199  79  27 295  67 347 255 239 195 187 139 107  39 119 179
>   [161] 395 371 201 123 159  91 211 355 103 327  95   7 167  35 267 155 387 383 335 315 259 135  15 113 279 373   4 353 265 127  45  37
>   [193]  19 276 224 361 260 288 336 368 348 292 268 252 120 108  96  88  32  16 340 156 388 372 356 332 304 220 188 168 136 124  56 236
>   [225]  28 244 392 184  76 380 232 100 116 112 256  72   8 280  64  52 208 172 152 148 360 352 192 160 144 284 216  48  84  92  36  20
>   [257] 212 272 264 200 128  80 180 364 196  12 132  40 324 308 176 164  68 316 312 384 300 344 328 248 204 140 296  24 320 228  60  44
>   [289] 233  65 400 376 240 163 104 396 307  75  14 325 269 262 234 382 294 206 198 374 310 362 318 386 358 330 278 210 298 282 122  98
>   [321]  34  26 174 142  46   6  62 118 190 202 114 322 286  38 242 394 342 266 162 130  30 182   2  74 314 290 246 194 170 126 158 378
>   [353] 350 254 226 214  70  18  10 366 354 186 150  86 306 102 338 346 134 250 138  94  78 390 274  58  42 258  66  90 146 370 222 218
>   [385] 326  82 110 270 334 178 166 398  22  50 238 106 154 302 230  54

and the 'plot' produces a reachability plot which I am not able to post because this is my first question on StackExchange...but if you run the R code you can easily get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue and after some research I think I finally understood how it works.

### BASIC IDEA:

I will now add the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm#Pseudocode) provided by Wikipedia, commented by me to explain it a little bit:

```
OPTICS(DB, eps, MinPts)
for each point p of DB
   p.reachability-distance = UNDEFINED
for each unprocessed point p of DB
   N = getNeighbors(p, eps)
   mark p as processed
   output p to the ordered list          # ordered list = final result
   # if p is a core point (has at least minPts in the specified radius)
   if (core-distance(p, eps, Minpts) != UNDEFINED)
      Seeds = empty priority queue
      # update the reachability-distance for every neighbour
      update(N, p, Seeds, eps, Minpts)
      # seeds will have the neighbours wich reachability-distance was updated
      # with the selected core point
      for each next q in Seeds
         N' = getNeighbors(q, eps)
         mark q as processed
         output q to the ordered list          # ordered list = final result
         # if the neighbor is a core point, grow the cluster as DBSCAN does
         if (core-distance(q, eps, Minpts) != UNDEFINED)
            update(N', q, Seeds, eps, Minpts)


update(N, p, Seeds, eps, MinPts)
coredist = core-distance(p, eps, MinPts)
# for every neighbor
for each o in N
   if (o is not processed)
      new-reach-dist = max(coredist, dist(p,o))
      if (o.reachability-distance == UNDEFINED) // o is not in Seeds
          o.reachability-distance = new-reach-dist
          Seeds.insert(o, new-reach-dist)
      else               // o in Seeds, check for improvement
          if (new-reach-dist < o.reachability-distance)
             o.reachability-distance = new-reach-dist
             Seeds.move-up(o, new-reach-dist)
```

From that pseudocode, I get the following:

- You will need an ordered list (to represent the reachability plot)
- Clusters will grow as they do in the DBSCAN algorithm
- The difference with DBSCAN is that now, when you get the neighborhood of a core point, for every neighbor you will have to calculate a so called *reachability distance*; if the neighbor hasn't one, just save the one you get and put that point next to the core one in the ordered list; if it had one already, compare the old one with the one obtained when processing the core point and go with the smaller one. If that one happens to be the new one, an update must be done in the ordered list to accommodate the point close to the core point.

### REACHABILITY DISTANCE

Now, it's crucial to understand what's the reachability distance. Also, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm#Basic_idea), we have:

[image]

From what I get, the **reachability distance** is the distance from every point to its closest core point.

### MEANING OF VALLEYS AND SPIKES IN REACHABILITY PLOT

If we take a look at the pseudocode, now it will be totally clear: when the final reachability distance for a point is super big, that means the point is far far away from the closest core point, so it doesn't belong to any cluster. That's why the spikes in the reachability plot denote the separation between clusters ... those spikes represent outliers. In fact, outliers are those points which reachability distance is greater than the specified epsilon (they aren't in any core point neighbourhood).

As for why valleys represent clusters, that has to be with the way the clusters grow; remember how DBSCAN works, growing a cluster following a chain of directly connected core points ... with OPTICS that's the same, considering also we keep track of the reachability distance of every point we add to the current cluster. Think about the way clusters are form to understand the meaning of the valleys.

Comment: Great!!. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @OmarRafique do not forget to mark my answer as accepted if you think it reaches your expectations - that way you will help me improve my image in the forum ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a reordering (permutation) of your data set, such that nearby points usually are close in the order.

Comment: Arent nearby points of a dataset already close together....thats why they are called nearby points...

Comment: Does it mean that in [1] 1 363 209 349 337 301 357 333 ...... sample number 1 and 363 are put together by the algorithm.

Comment: Close in the sequence, not coordinates. Sample 1 and sample 363 supposedly are close in coordinates, and they are close in the cluster order, but there were 362 points inbetween in the original data order.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed description is included in the R packages.

```
library("dbscan")
vignette("dbscan")
```

See Section **2.2. OPTICS: Ordering Points To Identify Clustering Structure**

> OPTICS provides an augmented ordering. The algorithm starting with a
>   point and expands it’s neighborhood like DBSCAN, but it explores the
>   new point in the order of lowest to highest core-distance. The order
>   in which the points are explored along with each point’s core- and
>   reachability-distance is the final result of the algorithm.